# Express.js hbs module - register partials from .hbs file

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I'm using the handlebars.js [hbs wrapper](https://github.com/donpark/hbs) in [express.js](http://expressjs.com/). I have templates working fine, but I'm needing to add in partials to be rendered with my views.

I'd like to do something like this:

```
hbs.registerPartial('headPartial', 'header'); 
// where "header" is an .hbs file in my views folder
```

However, it's throwing a "header partial can not be found".

I can make the registerPartial work if I pass a string of html to the second param, but I'd like to use separate view files for my partials.

I haven't found any documentation on this, but hoping I may just be missing something easy.

Does anyone know how to use view files in the registerPartial method?  If so, how do I implement this?

**UPDATE**

To give more context, let me add more code. 
Here is my "server" file - app.js

```
var express = require('express')
, routes = require('./routes')
, hbs = require('hbs');

var app = module.exports = express.createServer();

// Configuration

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
});

app.configure('production', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

// this is the line that generates the error
hbs.registerPartial('headPartial', 'header'); 

// What I'm expecting is for "headPartial" to be a compiled template partial 
// of the template within views/header.hbs, but it is not loading this way.
// If I do something like hbs.registerPartial('headPartial', '<p>test</p>');
// then it does work. I need to know how to pass an .hbs file to the
// registerPartial method.

// Routes
app.get('/', routes.index);

app.listen(3000);
```

And here is my routes.index file:

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' })
};
```

In my views folder, I have three templates:

```
views/
  header.hbs (this is my partial)
  index.hbs
  layout.hbs
```

In my index.hbs file, I'm calling the 'headPartial' partial with:

```
{{> headPartial}}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This [code](https://gist.github.com/3824204) loads all the partial templates in a directory and makes them available by filename:

```
var hbs = require('hbs');
var fs = require('fs');

var partialsDir = __dirname + '/../views/partials';

var filenames = fs.readdirSync(partialsDir);

filenames.forEach(function (filename) {
  var matches = /^([^.]+).hbs$/.exec(filename);
  if (!matches) {
    return;
  }
  var name = matches[1];
  var template = fs.readFileSync(partialsDir + '/' + filename, 'utf8');
  hbs.registerPartial(name, template);
});
```

Comment: Nice. A quick way to have all partials available when needed!

Answer (score 53):

For convenience, registerPartials provides a quick way to load all partials from a specific directory:

```
var hbs = require('hbs');
hbs.registerPartials(__dirname + '/views/partials');
```

Partials that are loaded from a directory are named based on their filename, where spaces and hyphens are replaced with an underscore character:

```
template.html      -> {{> template}}
template 2.html    -> {{> template_2}}
login view.hbs     -> {{> login_view}}
template-file.html -> {{> template_file}}
```

Cheers!

Comment: Hi, will it work for subdirectories also?

In this case, how can we get the views?

Thanks

Comment: This is great, but be aware that it loads partials asynchronously with a callback - you probably don't want to accept requests until this completes: [Helpers and Partials](https://github.com/pillarjs/hbs#helpers-and-partials)

Comment: Oh man, thanks a lot! I just spent half of hour figuring out why my partial `keypad-num.hbs` is not found when I requested it with: `{{> keypad-num}}`. you saved me a lot of time.

Comment: Voted up for the concise code of loading in an entire directory and explaining the fact that spaces and dashes are replaced with underscores. That was my issue that landed me here. I used a dash in my partial names but I was getting an error when trying to load it in with the dash. I saw the person asking this question had their partials in the same directory as their views, so hopefully this pushes them to split them into two sub-directories for a more organized app.

Comment: This should definitely be the accepted answer due to the fact that it's the correct way of using partials and it also covers the corner cases.

Comment: Didn't know hyphens were replaced with underscores...

Answer (score 12):

Looks like creating a variable and pulling in the template code manually works:

```
var hbs = require('hbs')
  , fs = require('fs')
  , headerTemplate = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/views/_header.hbs', 'utf8');
```

and later:

```
hbs.registerPartial('headPartial', headerTemplate);
```

Comment: this seems like a lot of extra work to sue partials in express3

Answer (score 5):

For me I had template file my-partial.hbs

Then I tried to access them via:

```
{{> my-partial }}
```

But the partial was stored in hbs as my_partial regardless of the filename.

This is thanks to hbs version 3.1.0 line 218

```
.slice(0, -(ext.length)).replace(/[ -]/g, '_').replace('\\', '/');
```

This is in the [readme](https://github.com/donpark/hbs)

Answer (score 1):

For me, I have a function like:

```
var hbs = require('hbs');
var fs = require('fs');    
var statupfunc = {
      registerHbsPartials : function(){
        //this is run when app start
        hbs.registerPartials(__dirname + "/" + resource.src.views + '/partials');        
      },
      registerOneHbsPartials : function(event){ 
        //this is run for gulp watch
        if(event.type == 'deleted')
        {
          return;
        }   
        var filename = event.path;
        var matches = /^.*\\(.+?)\.hbs$/.exec(filename);
        if (!matches) {
          return;
        }    
        var name = matches[1];    
        var template = fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf8');    
        hbs.registerPartial(name, template);    
      }
    };
```

Run **statupfunc.registerHbsPartials** at app startup and then register gulp watch with **statupfunc.registerOneHbsPartials** to register partials on new creation

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch(resource.src.views +  '/partials/*.*', statupfunc.registerOneHbsPartials);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My app structure (using ExpressJS & HBS-NPM) is:

```
  APP FOLDER
    -src
      app.js
      - routers
      - views
        -- partials
              header.hbs



const hbs = require('hbs')
hbs.registerPartials(path.join(__dirname,'views','partials'))
```

The above does the job of loading all partials in a single shot. Use this as long as you believe it doesn't impact your performance (loading all partials, even if not required).

And then, use this partial in any HBS file as follows:

```
{{> partial_file_name_without_hbs_extension}}
```

Example

```
 {{> header}
```