# Ajax request on html link click in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, node.js

I'm using nodejs to develop a website that extract data from an API using ajax requests. I use templates, .hbs files (index.hbs, area.hbs etc.). My problem is that I want to make a navbar (with text links), but since I use templates its not that easy. I need to use ajax. I have made ​​all the necessary routes, but I need help with the ajax request on the links. I have searched the internet for an answer, and tried a lot of different solutions, but nothing seems to solve my problem.

My navbar code:

```
<div id="navbar">
     <ul>
          <li>Companies</li>
          <li>Area</li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Server.js route code:

```
app.get('/area', routes.goToArea);
```

Routes.js code:

```
goToArea: function (req, res) {
            res.render('area');
        }
```

I think something along those lines could work:

```
var url = "/area";
        function area() {
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'GET',
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: A little unclear. You want to make `ajax` request on clicking on the navbar links right?

Comment: So whats the problem? You just need to bind the `click` events of those links and make `ajax` request in the handler. I believe that's pretty straightforward. Or you want a sample of it?

Comment: Yeah, I could really used a sample. Pretty new to this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you bind `click` event and make an `ajax` request

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.navbar a').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            'type': 'get',
            'url': '/area',
            'success': function (data) {
                // use the data
            }
        })
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Conceptionally spoken I would create partial layouts (or sections of html) which renders inside the global layout. This "Partial" should represend an Area.

I would also have a variable in the html (id or data-attribute) which represents the Area Identifier. 
then your could request something like

`http://myserver.com/area/tab1` or

`http://myserver.com/?area=tab1`

(depending how you want to structure your code / routing.

Then you whould request that partial via ajax and "Success" you would insert it into the Dom.

The docs here explain how to assemble the ajax call:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Here is a good read which might also help:

[Express.js hbs module - register partials from .hbs file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059914/express-js-hbs-module-register-partials-from-hbs-file)