# Include file content in handlebars

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, handlebars.js

Is it possible to take content of one file and include it into handlebars template using only power of handlebars? I just want to instert inline css into html.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      //here should be insterted content of file path/to/my.css
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    {{{ body }}}
  </body>
</html>
```

One solution that comes to my mind is to readFile in nodejs and put its content to `res.locals.inlinecss` and then simply print it. Any other ideas? Thanks

**UPDATE:**
This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059914/express-js-hbs-module-register-partials-from-hbs-file) uses `hbs` while I use `express-handlebars` which doesn't have support for registering partials. I don't want to change view engine.

**UPDATE2:**
This is how I resolved this.

```
var exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');

var template = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'path/to/my.css'), 'utf8');

var hbs = exphbs.create({
  defaultLayout: 'main',
  layoutsDir: path.resolve(__dirname, '../views/layout'),
  helpers: {
    cssContent: function(){
      return template;
    }
  }
});
```

I know that it could be more generic and lookup whole directory with css, but in this project for sure there won't more css files then one.

Comment: unfortunately express-handlebars doesn't have support for registering partials, but I use helper instead.